can't open Photo Gallery below Android 13
here is the permissions on my AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>

here is my build.gradle file
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}

When I try to open the gallery, the app will open the app settings, but unfortunately I can't find 'Photo and videos' permission at all to be allowed in 'settings' for Android 11 like the image below, I can only see 'Files and Media' permission which still I can't open the photo gallery. I don't have this issue on Android 13

I expect the app will open the gallery notification like this, instead of open the app settings

currently I am using Flutter and using Permission Handle Library and I use this code to ask permission to access the gallery
final status = await Permission.photos.request();

but it seems the status is always denied or permanentlyDenied so thats why I always open the app setting
  if (status == PermissionStatus.denied || status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
    openAppSettings();
    throw NoImageException("Photo gallery image permission is not granted");
  }


When I try to open the gallery, the app will open the app settings,  That is nonsense. Moreover you dont need any permission to use what you call the gallery or to let the user pick an image file.

await Permission.photos.request(); Pretty unclear which permission you are after here.

READ_MEDIA_IMAGES for your library is only for Android 13+ devices. For your library to read external storage below 13 you need permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

try exported true in mainefest and
shrinkResources false
minifyEnabled false
in app section. build.gradle

I can solve it using the code below, in you AndroidManifest.xml
        <!-- for below android 13-->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        
        <!-- for above android 13-->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
   

still in you AndroidManifest.xml add this one attribute on your application xml
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
</application>

on your flutter (dart) I use the code below, I use Permission Handler and also Device Info Plus
      import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
      import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

      // check Android version used
      final DeviceInfoPlugin info = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      final AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await info.androidInfo;
      final int androidVersion = int.parse(androidInfo.version.release);

      late PermissionStatus status;

      if (androidVersion >= 13) {
          status = await Permission.photos.request();
      } else {
          status = await Permission.storage.request();
      }
      

      if (status == PermissionStatus.denied || status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
        openAppSettings();
      }

